# How can I replace text of MessageBox (title,caption) with defined string?

Tags: c#, string, messagebox

I am trying to insert defined string to this code at places "paragraph" and "title" to replace them with text, which is defined in the strings, because I dont wanna write it in there, but I dont know how to do it:

*

```
MessageBox.Show("paragraph", "title",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

*
// Definitions

```
string dart = "Luke, I am your father"
string luke = "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!"
```

*
how can I make the MessageBox show the text from defined string ?
I hope it's clear... - Benedikz

Comment: You should perhaps start with an introductory book on the C# language.

Comment: Great idea, will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be like this,

```
MessageBox.Show(dart , luke,MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Helped a lot.